# ioredis infinite loop of connect event

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, ioredis

Not getting ready event to be triggered. The connected event is triggered multiple times but ready is not. What am I doing wrong? Also connected event should also be triggered only once.

Implementation:

```
const client = new Cluster(
    [
      {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 7000,
      },
    ],
    {
      dnsLookup: (address, callback) => callback(null, address),
      redisOptions: {
      },
    },
  );

client.on('ready', () => {
    log.info('Ready to use Redis');
  });

  client.on('connect', () => {
    log.info('Connected to Redis');
  });

  client.on('error', (x) => {
    log.error(`Disconnected from Redis`);
  });
```

Dockerhub:

```
redis-cluster:
    image: grokzen/redis-cluster
    environment:
      MASTERS: 1
      SLAVES_PER_MASTER: 1
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
```

ioredis version: 4.26.0